# Spherical triple integral for volume enclosed by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^2(x^2+y^2-z^2)$

Tags: integration

I need to find the volume of the figure that is bounded with surface

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^2(x^2+y^2-z^2)$$

using spherical coordinates $x=r\cos\phi \sin\theta, y=r\sin\phi \sin\theta, z=r\cos\theta$. My main problem is to find bounds for $\theta$ and $\phi$. For $r$ I easily get bounds $0\le r\le a\sqrt{1-2\cos^2 \theta}$. If I'd had two surfaces i would probably get bounds for theta  from another of them, but here not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clearly, your problem is rotational-symmetric, that is, independent of $\phi$. Have you attempted to draw your surface in XZ, for example?

Answer (score 2):

As volume is symmetric with respect to coordinate planes, then in first octant there is $1/8$ of volume. For angles we have restriction $1-2\cos^2 \theta = -\cos 2\theta \geqslant 0$
$$V=8\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin \theta d\theta \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi\int\limits_{0}^{a\sqrt{-\cos 2\theta}}r^2dr=\frac{4\pi a^3}{3}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1-2 \sin^2 t)^{3/2}d(\sin t)=\frac{\pi^2 a^3}{4\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates, the surface is $r= a\sqrt{1-2\cos^2\theta}$ with the range $\theta\in [\frac\pi4, \frac{3\pi}4]$, as seen below

[image]
The volume is then

\begin{align}
V& =2\pi \int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4}\int_0^{a\sqrt{1-2\cos^2\theta}}r^2\sin\theta drd\theta \\
& = \frac{2\pi}3 a^3\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4}
(1-2\cos^2\theta)^{3/2}\sin\theta d\theta \\
 & = \frac{2\pi}3 a^3 \cdot \frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt2}=
 \frac{\sqrt2\pi^2}{8}a^3\\
\end{align}

Comment: I am probably missing this part from trigonometry, but how did you get from $\cos 2\theta \le 0$, that theta is inside $[\frac{\pi}{4},3\frac{\pi}{4}]$

Comment: @Trevor - note that $1-2\cos^2\theta >0$, which confines $\theta$ within the specified range.